# JavaScript Function Constructor Chaining Using The apply() Function

Tags: javascript, html, object, constructor

I'm trying to understand some code Mozilla put out on constructor chaining. I've added comments to the parts I think I understand, but I'm still not clear on everything that's going on here. Can someone explain line by line what is going on in this code?

```
// Using apply() to chain constructors.
Function.prototype.construct = function (aArgs) {

    // What is this line of code doing?
    var fConstructor = this, fNewConstr = function () { fConstructor.apply(this, aArgs); };

    // Assign the function prototype to the new function constructor's prototype.
    fNewConstr.prototype = fConstructor.prototype;

    // Return the new function constructor.
    return new fNewConstr();
};

// Example usage.
function MyConstructor () {

    // Iterate through the arguments passed into the constructor and add them as properties.
    for (var nProp = 0; nProp < arguments.length; nProp++) {
        this["property" + nProp] = arguments[nProp];
    }
}

var myArray = [4, "Hello world!", false];
var myInstance = MyConstructor.construct(myArray);

// alerts "Hello world!"
alert(myInstance.property1); 

// alerts "true"
alert(myInstance instanceof MyConstructor); 

// alerts "MyConstructor"
alert(myInstance.constructor);
```

[The original code can be found here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this is an alternate way to call a constructor function, which gives you the opportunity to wrap the constructor call in another function.  I'll focus on the line you are confused about.  `fConstructor` is set to `this`, which references our original constructor function, in this example that is `MyConstructor`.  `fNewConstr` is the constructor which will override the original constructor.  Within that `fNewConstr` you could implement additional code not found in the `MyConstructor`.  Within `fNewConstr`, we call `fConstructor` using the Function [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method, passing `this` as the context, and the `aArgs` array passed to the construct method.  Then we set the prototype of the `fNewConstr` to the `fConstructor` prototype to complete the inheritance chain.  Finally, we return a new instance of `fNewConstr`.  Prefixing the new keyword to a function call creates a new object, sets its prototype to the prototype of the function, and invokes the function in the context of the new item.  Because we apply the `fConstructor` method with the `fNewConstr`'s context, the result is essentially the same as calling `new MyConstructor()`.  Make sense?  Or do I need to go into more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. That makes sense. What kind of scenarios would you use for this type of constructor manipulation?

Comment: You'd use something similar for any sort of OO inheritance situation.  Lets say that you have a constructor function that creates Animal objects, and you want to extend the Animal constructor to create a Dog constructor.  You may want to do some tasks specific to Dog objects in the Dog constructor, but you still want to apply the original Animal constructor to the object.  This pattern allows you to do that.

Comment: This seems very similar to c# instance constructors.

Comment: Yes, this is very similar to how overriding constructors works in a language that implements class inheritence.